# Serialize relationship in SQLModel

Tags: fastapi, sqlmodel

Lets say I have 2 models in relationship and an endpoint in sqlmodel and fastapi:

```
class Search(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int = Field(default=None, nullable=True, primary_key=True, index=True)
    videos: list["Video"] = Relationship(back_populates="search")


class Video(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int = Field(default=None, nullable=True, primary_key=True, index=True)
    search_id: int = Field(foreign_key="search.id")
    search: "Search" = Relationship(back_populates="videos")

@router.get("/", response_model=Video)
def read_videos(
        db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db),
    ):
    return db.query(Video).first()
```

This works fine, but does not return nested dictonary with search relationship. If I simply create

```
class VideoResponse(SQLModel):
    id: int
    search_id: int
    search: Search
```

and change response_model to VideoResponse, everything works as I wish. However it brings some redundancy which in fact SQLModel aims to remove. Is it possible to solve this in some clean way?
Would it be possible to make SQLModel serialize relationship by default?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [SQLModel's documentation](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/fastapi/relationships/#why-arent-we-getting-more-data) you can reduce redundancy like shown below:

```
class SearchBase(SQLModel):
    id: int = Field(default=None, nullable=True, primary_key=True, index=True)

class Search(SearchBase, table=True):
    videos: list["Video"] = Relationship(back_populates="search")

class VideoBase(SQLModel):
    id: int = Field(default=None, nullable=True, primary_key=True, index=True)
    search_id: int = Field(foreign_key="search.id")

class Video(VideoBase, table=True):
    search: "Search" = Relationship(back_populates="videos")

class VideoResponse(VideoBase):
    search: SearchBase

@router.get("/", response_model=VideoResponse)
def read_videos(
        db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db),
    ):
    return db.query(Video).first()
```

You can't get rid of all the redundancy because if you use models with relationship as an output model it might cause an infinite loop.

Comment: That's not quite right. In your example, there's nothing preventing "search: SearchBase" from being "search: Search" without running into infinite loop. The problem is not in the annotation of "search" field, but either in assigning the "Relationship" value to it, or in the table=True parameter. I was hoping SQLModel code can be adjusted so none of those 2 prevents actual serialization in response_model.

Comment: I have recently learned all the SQLModel documentation and according to it the only one way to return object with relations is to avoid recursion in your output models. If you use `VideoResponse` from my example as an output model you don't have recursion. If you use `Video` as an output model you have recursion: it will cause querying related `Search` objects, and when Pydantic will validate these nested `Search` models it will cause querying `Video` objects, which will cause querying `Search` objects and so on..

Comment: I think it's possible to add the support of behavior you want to SQLModel library - to let use models with recursion in relations as an output models, but limit the depth of recursion. But for now SQLModel doesn's support this, as I know.